# Как вывести из таблицы Oracle итоговые суммы за все месяцы определенного года (в т.ч. вывести 0 в те месяцы, за которые нет ни одной записи)

Tags: sql, oracle

Вывести суммы за те месяцы, в которые регистрировался хотябы один заказ - получилось без проблем:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM ORDER_DATE) as month, SUM(ORDER_TOTAL)
FROM oe.orders
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM ORDER_DATE) = 2007  
GROUP BY EXTRACT(MONTH FROM ORDER_DATE)
ORDER BY month
```

Как вывести нулевую сумму за месяц в котором не регистрировалось ни одного заказа?

Пример данных из таблицы oe.orders:

```
| ORDER_ID | ORDER_DATE                   | ORDER_MODE | CUSTOMER_ID | ORDER_STATUS | ORDER_TOTAL | SALES_REP_ID | PROMOTION_ID |
|----------|------------------------------|------------|-------------|--------------|-------------|--------------|--------------|
| 2458     | 16-AUG-07 03.34.12.234359 PM | direct     | 101         | 0            | 78279.6     | 153          |  -           |
| 2397     | 19-NOV-07 02.41.54.696211 PM | direct     | 102         | 1            | 42283.2     | 154          |  -           |
| 2454     | 02-OCT-07 05.49.34.678340 PM | direct     | 103         | 1            | 6653.4      | 154          |  -           |
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: А пример данных вы можете дать?

Comment: Генерировать опорный календарь (полный список месяцев года), и к нему уже привязывать имеющиеся данные.